# Asp.net accept client certs which chain up to a set of root CA's

Tags: asp.net, security, pki

I want to make Asp.net accept client certs which chain up to a set of root CA's. How do I do it? On my example asp.net mvc application which I run on my development machine on iis express from visual studio I made this changes to iis config applicationhost.config:

```
<location path="MusicStore/Store">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <access sslFlags="SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert" />
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Now I get HTTP 403.7 error when accesing MusicStore/Store location without any option to select certificate. I want user to select a cert from browser, is it possible?